# Why can't I stream transaction results from Neo4J Bolt Driver

Tags: java, neo4j

I'm not able to figure out why I can't stream the results like this:

```
try (var session = driver.session()) {
  var maybeRecord = session.executeRead(tx -> tx.run("MATCH (c:Category { id:$id }) RETURN c", parameters("bggId", id))) //
                    .stream() //
                    .findFirst();
}
```

When I do this, I get an error:

```
org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.ClientException: org.neo4j.driver.Result is not a valid return value, it should be consumed before producing a return value
```

I understand what that error means, and I can change my code to do the whole  `while (results.hasNext()) { }` business, but it's very verbose. Is there a way I can do it similar to streaming while keeping within the bounds of consuming the Result?

Comment: I think you're supposed to chain the stream onto `run()`, not `executeRead()`.

Answer (score 0):

Sooo, parenthesis are my enemy.

```
var maybeRecord = session.executeRead(tx -> tx.run("MATCH (c:Category { id:$id }) RETURN c", parameters("bggId", id)))
                    .stream()
                    .findFirst();
```

Should be:

```
var maybeRecord = session.executeRead(tx -> tx.run("MATCH (c:Category { id:$id }) RETURN c", parameters("bggId", id))
                    .stream()
                    .findFirst());
```

Thanks @shmosel for the comment that answered this question.